# Postgresql EXCLUDE constraint not triggering ON CONFLICT when INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11, exclusion-constraint

I have defined this table:

```
CREATE TABLE market.price_history (
    item_id bigint NOT NULL,
    valid_time tstzrange DEFAULT tstzrange(now(), 'infinity'),
    sale_price money NOT NULL,
    promo_code bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    EXCLUDE USING gist(item_id WITH =, valid_time WITH &&),
    EXCLUDE USING gist(item_id WITH =, sale_price WITH =, valid_time WITH &&)
);
```

But when I'm doing this SQL:

```
WITH new_row_valid_time as(
    SELECT tstzrange(MAX(upper(valid_time)), 
                     'infinity'::timestamptz) as adjacent_valid_time 
    FROM market.price_history 
    WHERE item_id = 11
)
INSERT INTO market.price_history as ph
(item_id, valid_time, sale_price, promo_code)
VALUES(11,                        -- same id as existent row
       (SELECT adjacent_valid_time 
        FROM new_row_valid_time), -- adjacent range for existent row
       11.83,                     -- same price as the existent row
       False)
ON CONFLICT (item_id, sale_price, valid_time) DO
UPDATE SET valid_time = tstzrange(lower(ph.valid_time), 'infinity'::timestamptz)
WHERE ph.item_id = excluded.item_id
    AND ph.sale_price = excluded.sale_price
    AND upper(ph.valid_time) = lower(excluded.valid_time);
```

I'm expecting the `ON CONFLICT` clause to be executed, given that there is some row to be inserted having the same `item_id`, `sale_price` and a `valid_time` adjacent to the existent one. Instead I'm getting this:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

Do I misunderstand something? I believe the exclusion constraint in the second `EXCLUDE` clause involves the same 3 columns. I'm searching the docs but the `ON CONFLICT` instructions are not that clear to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) somewhat tersely remarks:

> Note that exclusion constraints are not supported as arbiters with `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`.

Looking at the source code makes the case clearer:

- You can never use an exclusion constraint with `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`.
- You can, however, use

  ```
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT price_history_item_id_valid_time_excl DO NOTHING
  ```

  That is, you can use a named exclusion constraint with `DO NOTHING`.
- There is no “constraint inference” with exclusion constraints, i.e., even in the `DO NOTHING` case you cannot just specify the indexed expressions in parentheses and have PostgreSQL find the corresponding exclusion constraint.